# Auto Forward mails to gmail from Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2003, forwarding, windows-firewall

I have a highly secured computer windows server 2003 where my outlook express is configured, i want to forward all the mails coming from Outlook to gmail. I put some auto forward rule in outlook but its not working. (May be auto forwarding is disabled).

I can forward mails manually.

Is there anyway to get rid off this problem?

Answer (score 7):

I have written some VBA script to do this *bypass the server's disabling of auto-forward".  Basically it mimics the user forwarding the email rather than the server doing an auto-forward.

It's pretty simple:

```
Sub AutoForwardAllSentItems(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim strMsg As String
Dim myFwd As Outlook.MailItem

Set myFwd = Item.Forward

myFwd.Recipients.Add "email@email.com"
myFwd.Send
Set myFwd = Nothing 
End Sub
```

It's beyond the scope of this post to give detailed instructions, but here's a summary:

1. Add the above code in the Visual Basic editor of Outlook (Alt-F11 should get your started).  Be sure to change email@email.com to the address where you want the mail to go
2. Tell Outlook to run this code for each inbound message (Tools -> Rules and Alerts -> New Rule -> Check Messages when they arrive -> Next -> YES -> Checkbox "Run a Script" -> Then select the script you just created.

Now Outlook should automatically forward each email you receive, but it won't be blocked by the Admin as an "Auto-forward".

Comment: Nitpick - the variable 'strMsg' in the code sample is never used.

Comment: Also wanted to note one VERY big caveat with this (though it's a nice solution) -- Outlook HAS to be open when the email comes in for this to work. So if you're away from work on vacation for example, the forward won't be processed.

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same problem, and here's my solution:
* Add your gmail account into Outlook
* In our Outlook "Rule", instead of selecting "Forward", select "Move a Copy to a Folder"
* As the target folder, select a folder in your Gmail account

Answer (score 2):

Basically, with outlook and exchange you by default set up server rules. This means that the rules are applied on the server and on reception of an email regardless of whether your client (outlook) is running. With exchange it is possible to block the automatic forwarding of emails to external adresses (and it seems that your system administrators have done so). The reason it works for manual forwarding is that this is a very different process. It happens on the client, and for the server it looks like just sending any other email.

The reason for such configuration of the server is generally to prevent corporate information and secrets to be leaked out. As this is a valid concern, you probably won't have luck convincing your admins to let you forward your emails to gmail.

Comment: i could see my auto forwarded messages in sent item, but its not reaching in my gmail inbox

Comment: This probably means that the blocking happens at a different stage. The outward email can be configured to go through a gateway server that blocks things. That would mean that the originating server things it is sent (and puts the mail in your sent mail folder), but that the intermediary blocks things from going out.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider adding the email accounts you want to forward to gmail via the accounts tab. You can add both POP and IMAP accounts now.

Comment: which email account i need to add, my email account is already configured in outlook

Comment: You mean to say if i configure my gmail account in the outlook it will work ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to ask your mail server admin to set up a server-side forward to your GMail account.

Otherwise, as Mr Matt suggests, adding the account directly to GMail is likely to prove most efficacious.

Comment: This is not possible, and i am not doing anything illegal here because i am a contractor i just want to get it to my offshore email inbox

Comment: I'm interested that you say it's not illegal, because nobody seems to be suggesting you are.  Although now that you bring the subject up...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by auto forwarding rule, but have you added it as a normal filter / rule in your email filtering? There is an option there to forward or forward as attachment.

Comment: i could see my auto forwarded messages in sent item, but its not reaching in my gmail inbox