# Autoforward Outlook emails to external only under certain circumstances

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, vba

Is there a modification that can be made to the VBA code provided in [this response](https://superuser.com/questions/19159/auto-forward-mails-to-gmail-from-outlook) from an earlier post that would only forward email from a certain email address rather than forwarding everything?  Essentially, mimicking an outlook autoforward rule with a condition that only messages from email@email.com get sent?

> I have written some VBA script to do this *bypass the server's
>   disabling of auto-forward". Basically it mimics the user forwarding
>   the email rather than the server doing an auto-forward.
>   It's beyond the scope of this post to give detailed instructions, but
>   here's a summary:
>
> Add the above code in the Visual Basic editor of Outlook (Alt-F11 should get your started). Be sure to change email@email.com to the
>   address where you want the mail to go
>
> Tell Outlook to run this code for each inbound message (Tools -> Rules and Alerts -> New Rule -> Check Messages when they arrive ->
>   Next -> YES -> Checkbox "Run a Script" -> Then select the script you
>   just created.
>
> Now Outlook should automatically forward each email you receive, but
>   it won't be blocked by the Admin as an "Auto-forward".

Code:

```
Sub AutoForwardAllSentItems(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim strMsg As String
Dim myFwd As Outlook.MailItem

Set myFwd = Item.Forward

myFwd.Recipients.Add "email@email.com"
myFwd.Send
Set myFwd = Nothing 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an `if` statement using the [sender address](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869056(v=office.15).aspx) -

```
Sub AutoForwardAllSentItems(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim strMsg As String
Dim myFwd As Outlook.MailItem

Set myFwd = Item.Forward

If myFwd.Sender = "sender@email.com" then
myFwd.Recipients.Add "email@email.com"
myFwd.Send
End if

Set myFwd = Nothing 
End Sub
```

---

Or, the easier way, would be in [setting the rule](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/571):

> Tell Outlook to run this code for each inbound message (Tools -> Rules
>   and Alerts -> New Rule -> Check Messages when they arrive -> Next ->
>   YES -> Checkbox "Run a Script" -> Then select the script you just
>   created.

Just tell outlook to run the code **if the message is from a certain address**.